# Convert Image (.png) to array 2d

Tags: c#, arrays, image

Haw Can Convert The image To array 2d All The White color 0 And Otherwise 1 In array 2d using Visual studio 2012 C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load your image with the [Image.FromFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Image.FromFile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method and cast it to a [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If your bitmap is small, you can call [Bitmap.GetPixel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the value of each pixel, you can query the size of the image with [Bitmap.Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.width%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Bitmap.Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.height%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This is a slow method, a better alternative is to call [Bitmap.LockBits()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Bitmap.LockBits%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can find lots of tutorials about this method, there is a sample on MSDN as well. This all happens with the System.Drawing assembly.

There is a completely different graphics library implementation in .NET, associated with WPF. I'll just give you a starting point with this, the concept is similar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.copypixels%28v=vs.110%29.aspx